# Connected arduino (ESP 8266) device over USB not detecting

Tags: android, serial-port, usb

I am trying to send data/text from Android to arduino (ESP 8266) device. First of all I am trying to detect if any device is connected or not, but there always showing no device is connected.

I have followed by Android host and accessory mode.

My trying code.

```
accessory = (UsbAccessory)getIntent().getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_ACCESSORY);
        inoutBytes= editText.getText().toString().getBytes();
        usbManager= (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
        usbDevices = usbManager.getDeviceList();
        accessoryList = usbManager.getAccessoryList();

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (!usbDevices.isEmpty()) {
                    Log.v("ksjdhfkjdf", "shdf" + accessoryList.length);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"device connected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"device not connected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
```

Can you please tell me how to do the thing I want?

Comment: Please make sure the power from the USB port of the Android device is enough for your Arduino (ESP8266). Try using an external power source just USB for data connection

Comment: yes i have ensured the power, but not worked yet

Comment: Do you Android device supports OTG? Which Android OS version are you using... You are talking about accesory mode, but I think you are confusing it with OTG. Look here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/

Comment: yes OTG supported. OS-Marshmallow. i tried both way, but did not respond